# how to filter a lines in a text file using two specific words

Tags: python-2.7

I need to filter all lines that have a specific word in a text file and write into another text file.This is my example code.

```
import os
with open("info.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l for l in lines if "udc.exe" in l]
    with open("Lines.txt", "w") as f1:
     new=f1.writelines(lines)
f.close()
f1.close()
```

But i need to filter a line with two specific words.How can i do it.can you please guide me for this.

Comment: user AND in your condidtion:lines = [l for l in lines if ("udc.exe" in l and "something" in l)]

Comment: This is not working for me.I have using "OR: Instead of AND.Then it working